# Fock Space and Coherent state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, many-body, quantum-states, coherent-states

Can a coherent photon state also belong to the Fock space? If yes, under what conditions? For example I read that
$$\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\bigg\}\exp\bigg\{-\sum_i\alpha_ia_i^{\dagger}\bigg\}\exp\bigg\{\sum_i\alpha^*_ia_i\bigg\}|0\rangle$$
lies in the Fock space if the criterion
$$\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2<\infty$$
is met. Why does this hold?

I know that the Fock space contains states whose norm is finite. If this has something to do with that, I can not see the connection. And even if something like that holds (or the above criterion is met), does the Fock space contain $n$ particle states even when $n\rightarrow\infty$? Because if we expand the exponentials, we can have such states even if the criterion is met.

Thanks a lot.

By the way, $a_i^{\dagger}$ and $a_i$ are the usual bosonic creation and annihilation operators and $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_i^*$ are numerical coefficients.

Source: Faddeev-Kulish paper "Asymptotic conditions and infrared divergences in QED" written in 1970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak h$ be the $1$-particle Hilbert space, $|\psi_i\rangle$ an orthonormal basis and $\mathcal F$ the bosonic Fock space (**edit** : for indistinguishable bosons), which is given by :
$$\mathcal F = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}S^n\mathfrak h$$
Here, $S^n \mathfrak h$ is the symmetrized $n$-fold tensor product of $\mathfrak h$, ie the space of $n$-particle states.

$\mathcal F$ is a Hilbert space, with the different $n$-particle subspaces being orthogonal. Therefore, there are $n$-particle states with arbitrary high values of $n$ as well as states which are superposition involving arbitrary high values of $n$.

Now, let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto the $n$-particle subspace, $\underline \alpha = \{\alpha_i\}$ a collection of complex numbers and set (formally, for now) :
$$|\underline \alpha\hspace{0.3mm}\rangle = \exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\bigg\}\exp\bigg\{-\sum_i\alpha_ia_i^{\dagger}\bigg\}\exp\bigg\{\sum_i\alpha^*_ia_i\bigg\}|0\rangle$$

Then, we have :
\begin{align}
P_n  |\underline \alpha\hspace{0.3mm}\rangle &= \frac{1}{n!}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\bigg\}\bigg(-\sum_i\alpha_ia_i^{\dagger}\bigg)^n|0\rangle
\end{align}
In particular, we have :
\begin{align}
P_1|\underline \alpha\hspace{0.3mm}\rangle &= \exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\bigg\}\bigg(-\sum_i\alpha_ia_i^{\dagger}\bigg)|0\rangle\\
&= -\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\bigg\}\sum_i \alpha_i|\psi_i\rangle
\end{align}

This is a well-defined state of $\mathfrak h$ only if $\sum_i |\alpha_i|^2 <\infty$, ie this condition is necessary. If this condition holds, we can define :
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sum_i |\alpha_i|^2} &=\sqrt{\sum_i |\alpha_i|^2} \\
b &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_i |\alpha_i|^2}}\sum_i \alpha_i^* a_i
\end{align}

and check that $[b,b^\dagger] = 1$ : $b$ is an annihilation operator and :
$$|\underline \alpha\hspace{0.3mm}\rangle = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}|\underline\alpha|^2\right)\exp(-|\underline\alpha|b^\dagger)\exp(|\underline\alpha|b)|0\rangle
$$
We can compute the norm of this state by projecting it onto every $n$-particle subspace :
\begin{align}
\langle \hspace{.3mm} \underline\alpha|\underline \alpha\hspace{0.3mm}\rangle &= e^{-|\underline\alpha|^2} \frac{1}{n!^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\langle 0 |e^{-|\underline\alpha|b}P_ne^{-|\underline\alpha|b^\dagger}|0\rangle \\
&=  e^{-|\underline\alpha|^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{|\underline\alpha|^{2n}}{n!^2}\langle 0 |b^n (b^\dagger)^n|0\rangle \\
&=e^{-|\underline\alpha|^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{|\underline\alpha|^{2n}}{n!} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

**Edit** :
The Fock space is **generated** by states with a definite and finite number of particles. But, given an orthonormal basis of such states, you can form linear combination with $L^2$ coefficients to form other states in the Fock space. In general, a (normalized) state $|\Psi\rangle\in\mathcal F$ has :
$$1 = \langle \Psi|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \langle\Psi|P_n|\Psi\rangle$$
This state has a probability $p_n = \langle\Psi|P_n|\Psi\rangle$ to contain $n$-particles. This probability distribution does not need to have finite support and it is even possible for it to have an infinite expectation value : $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} np_n = +\infty$. However, it must be a probability distribution, ie it must sum up to $1$.

**Edit 2** : As mentionned in the comments, given an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak h$, we can build an orthonormal basis of the bosonic Fock space using occupation numbers, with vectors of the forms $|\{n_i\}\rangle$ where the $n_i$ are non-negative integers, all but a finite number of whom are zero.

If we consider the subset of those vectors with $\sum_i n_i = n$, we get an orthonormal basis for the $n$-particle subspace. By concatening those, we get a basis for the full Fock space.

An $n$-particle subspace (with $n$ fixed) can be finite dimensional if $\dim\mathfrak h<\infty$, but the bosonic Fock space is always infinite dimensional.

Comment: Hi @SolubleFish and thanks for the answe. It seems that you are implying that the criterion of the sum of the square of the numerical coefficients needs to be finite such that we are able to normalize our states. That is something I understand now. However, by employing the argument involving the orthogonal projection operator and since the aforesaid operator can have arbitrarily large dimensionality, doesn't this imply that it is an infinite dimensional operator and hence the Fock space allows for particle states with infinite number of particles??

Comment: I am asking whether or not a state in Fock space can contain an infinite number of particles because in the paper I am reading, the authors claim that the Fock space is formed by states that are nonvanishing for sequences for which $\sum_in_i<\infty$, where $n_i$ are the integers indicating the occupancy of the state with label $i$

Comment: So, if the last statement is true, then the total amount of particles should be finite.

Comment: The statement is true, but when they say that the Fock state "is formed by those states", they mean that those state form an orthonormal basis, not that any state is of this form. This does not prohibit states with an infinite *expected* number of particles $\langle \hat N\rangle_\Psi = \infty$ (see the edit in my answer)

Comment: Hi and thanks again for the answer. It has been very helpful. So, I realise now that infinite particle state does not necessarily mean that the Fock space basis contains vectors with infinite particles (so I guess that such vectors are formed by some combination of the basis vectors)... Please correct me if I am wrong. However, you have written the normalized inner product as a sum that runs from zero to infinity. Doesn't that imply that there exists an infinite dimensional orthonormal basis $\{|n=0>,|n=1>,...\}$??

Comment: Well yes, though I am not sure where the confusion lies. Even if the one-particle subspace $\mathfrak h$ has finite dimension $d$, then the $n$-particle subspace has dimension ${d+n- 1 \choose n}$ and the Fock space is infinite dimensional.

Comment: I think the confusion lies in the fact that we have defined a basis that is infinite dimensional and whose elements are particle number eigenstates (your normalization equation) and therefore we have infinite particle number. Then we suggest that states for which the particle number is finite form an orthonormal basis (your explanation of the FK paper). Doesn't the last proposition contradict the first one?? We can not have both finite and infinite dimensional bases, right?? (sorry if I am being too stubborn or if my linear algebra is rusty)

Comment: The Fock space is always infinite dimensional, I have not claimed the contrary. I tried to add an edit to explain things further. The particle number eigenstates have finite particle number (by definition). This does not prohibit us from building other states, which are no longer eigenstates, with an infinite expected particle number.

Comment: Okay yes, now things are clear!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SolubleFish. Why do you restrict to the symmetrized product?  That would certainly be true for *indistinguishable* photons (or other indistinguishable bosons) but quite generally one can easily imagine a Fock space containing subspace of arbitrary permutation symmetry for partially or totally distinguishable particles or for spatial-only degrees of freedom.

Comment: @SolubleFish as an explicit example, consider 2 Gaussian photons entering a beam splitter, as in the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect.  Then only when the Gaussian profiles exactly overlap is the Fock space totally symmetric; else it contains the pieces of mixed symmetry.  This is true *a fortiriori* if the input state contains more than 2 photons.

Comment: I considered only the symmetrized Fock space for simplicity. I believe that changing the symmetries/whether particles are distinguishable does not significantly change the answer to OP's problem. (Also, in a way, fully (anti-)symmetric Fock spaces are the most fundamental, and we get distinguishable photons by restricting to a certain set of modes)

Comment: @SolubleFish not sure I agree with your last comment about "fundamental" but I won't die on a hill for that.  I would upvote if you would clarify you're discussing *indistinguishable* particles: there is confusion with many that symmetric states *always* appear for boson (or antisymmetric states always appear for fermions) without recognizing the requirement of indistinguishability...

Comment: @SolubleFish as another explicit example where the n-fold tensor product does not have a definite permutation symmetry, consider the decomposition of the $n$-particle states in  nuclear symplectic model as in Rowe, D. J., B. G. Wybourne, and P. H. Butler. "Unitary representations, branching rules and matrix elements for the non-compact symplectic groups." Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General 18.6 (1985): 939. This decomposition is actually quite complicated...  The fully antisymmetric subspace then only occurs once spin is coupled to the Fock states.

Comment: I have edited the precision in. I agree that this is a confusion worth dispelling here. What I meant (rather unprecisely) was in the line of what I explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648257) which seem to apply to the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect. It is not meant to be a strict and general theorem though, and I will take a look at your last reference on that matter.